# How was my suggested edit not useful?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review

I just [suggested an edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/138877/revisions) to the question [Extracting text using sed does not work as expected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/138877/23408). After a few minutes I checked back and found that an edit had been committed to the question. It was *my* edit, with a few cosmetic/stylistic changes. (For example, I had used “…” quotes around strings that were also in back-ticks; OK, I accept that that’s non-standard. And indentation and a blockquote that I had added were gone.) But my name was nowhere to be seen, and I didn’t get my two points of reputation. Was this a correct edit review?

Comment: Your *suggested edit* put words in the op's mouth.

Comment: So what? My suggested edit wasn’t rejected outright; the person who reviewed it kept (i.e., validated) the content of my edit, making only stylistic changes, keeping the Edit Summary unchanged, but denied me “credit”” for it.

Comment: this is a valid point, and is one i did not previously see. This has completely changed my own perspective on this question. Could you make any edit to this at all so that i might reverse my vote? I aplogize for not having seen it sooner.

Comment: Related: [Is it typical for an edit to be hijacked and then attributed to someone else?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/7368/150988)

Comment: If it happens only twice a year (and that's once a year each on two different sites), that probably doesn't qualify as "typical".

Comment: Scott - that's another well-made point.

Answer (score 9):

Look at the differences between your suggestion and the improvement:

- Removed an excessive amount of whitespace before the input/output/commands
- Made the commands blocks instead of inline formatting, which they should be as they're on their own line.
- Removed the note from a quote block, as it doesn't really belong in one.

This ends up correcting about half of your changes. I would probably have left your edit marked helpful as I'm generous with such things, but I understand why the rejector rejected it.